# Find objects with a certain Enum attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: %w(employee admin manager)
end
```

How can I find all users with the role "admin"?

This doesn't return any user: `User.where(role: "admin")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like

```
User.where(role: User.roles['admin'])
```

Also

```
User.admin
```

works for your case

Comment: ActiveRecord also generates scopes based on the enumeration values, so he can also use `User.admin`.